# Cannot resolve promise in object

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to fetch file and return promise in one method of object and then use this data inside another method of same object:

```
const translator = {
    currentLanguage: '',
    getText() {
        fetch('js/text.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    resolve(res);
                });
            });
    },
    fillText(lang) {
        this.getText()
            .then((res) => {
                console.log('in fill text: ');
                console.log(res);
            });
    },
};

translator.checkLanguage();
translator.fillText(translator.currentLanguage);
```

It console.log JSON from text.json in getText method correctly. My text.json is valid json file. I got error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>       at Object.fillText (translator.js:35)

35 line is `.then((res) => {` in fillText method. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to *return* the `fetch` in `getText` so that it's accessible to consumers of `getText`. Otherwise, `getText()` returns `undefined`. `getText() { return fetch('js/text.json')`

Comment: You dont need to create a new promise inside the last `then()` just to resolve the response. Remove the last `then()` part and return the `fetch().then()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never returned anything from `getText()`. Change this:

```
fetch('js/text.json')
```

to this:

```
return fetch('js/text.json')
```

Also, using the Promise constructor in the second `then` callback of `getText` is redundant, you can directly return the value:

```
.then(res => {
  console.log(res);
  return res;
});
```

It will, by default, be treated as a resolved promise.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to return it

```
  getText() {
       return fetch('js/text.json')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return new Promise((resolve) => {
                    resolve(res);
                });
            });
    }
```